# How to unscramble a list of words using a HashMap?

Tags: java, string, methods, hashmap

Basically I will be given two large input files. One will be a list of words, the other will be that list of those same words, but the words will be scrambled. I have to use a HashMap to get the list of words and scrambled words and then print the scrambled word with the real word next to it in alphabetical order.

For example:

rdib bird

tca cat

gdo dog

etc.

I'm having some trouble so far. I have created a method to sort and get the key from the words, but I'm not sure where to go from there. I think I still need to work with the scrambled words and then print everything out. Any help explaining these things would be much appreciated, for this is my first time using a HashMap. My current, very incomplete code is below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Project5
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        BufferedReader dictionaryList = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[0] ) );
        BufferedReader scrambleList = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[1] ) );

        HashMap<String, String> dWordMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 

        while (dictionaryList.ready())
        {
            String word = dictionaryList.readLine();
            dWordMap.put(createKey(word), word);
        }
        dictionaryList.close();

        while (scrambleList.ready())
        {
            String scrambledWords = scrambleList.readLine();
            List<String> dictionaryWords = dWordMap.get(createKey(scrambledWords));
            System.out.println(scrambledWords + " " + dictionaryWords);
        }
        scrambleList.close();
    }   
    private static String createKey(String word)
    {
        char[] characterWord = word.toCharArray(); 
        Arrays.sort(characterWord);
        return new String(characterWord);
    }
```

Comment: Store the words in a map from `wordWithOrderedLetters => actualWord`.

Comment: You should also change this line: 

`BufferedReader scrambleList = 
new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[0] ) );`   

to: 

`BufferedReader scrambleList = 
new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[1] ) );`

because you are just reading the file otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the dWordMap just `HashMap<String, String>`. For the line you're not sure of, do `dWordMap.put(createKey(word), word)`.

Then loop through the scrableList and the word is `dWordMap.get(createKey(scrambledWord))`.

You should probably also handle the case that the scrambled word is not in the original word list.

---

The key concept to understand about a HashMap is that it makes it O(1) to test if the map contains a given key, and O(1) to retrieve the value associated with a given key. This means these operations take constant time--whether the map has 5 elements or 5000, it will take the same time to determine if the map contains `"ehllo"`. If you want to check these two lists (dictionary and scrambled), you need a key that will be the same for both. As you have started to do in your solution, sorting the letters in the word is a good choice. So your HashMap will look something like this:

```
{
  "ehllo": "hello",
  "dlorw": "world"
}
```

One pass through the dictionary list builds that map, then another pass through it takes the scrambled word, sorts the letters in it, then checks the map to find the unscrambled word.

Comment: `Map<String, String>` won't work because "dog" and "god" may be scrambled to same string.

Comment: @talex The problem description is a bit vague, but I think it suggests that the word list will be such that there's a one-to-one relationship between scrambled and unscrambled words.

Comment: @talex It doesn't matter. If the scrambled list has "ogd", there is no way to know whether to return "dog" or "god". We could define a rule for such a case (say, return the unscrambled word which comes first alphabetically), but there is no such requirement in the problem as stated. If we did define such a rule, we would still use `<String, String>`

Comment: @talex My solution implicitly uses the rule "if two dictionary words have the same letters, return the one that occurred last in the dictionary list". How to handle this edge case would be a good question to whoever provided the requirements.

Comment: @Kip sorry for the vague description; there should only be one instance of each word. When I loop through the scramble list using dWordMap.get(createKey(scrambledWord)), I get an error saying String cannot be converted to List<String>. I've edited my post to include the loop.

Comment: @Alex it is because you defined `dictionaryWords` as `List<String>`. When you have `HashMap<K, V>`, you call `get` method passing an object of type `K`, and it will return an object of type `V`. So for a `HashMap<String, String>`, the `get` method is going to return a `String`, not a list of strings.

Comment: @Alex your variable names inside that loop indicate that perhaps you are thinking about the problem wrong, or that the problem has been stated wrong. The variables there should be `scrambledWord` and `dictionaryWord` (singular, not plural), as they are both `String` objects that contain only one word.

Comment: @Kip that makes sense, thank you. With the variable names, that was just a mistake. I'm still working to get past making those little errors, and I'm trying to get a better hold on the concepts

Comment: @Alex I'm guessing you're a student, so here's some free advice. In the real world, requirements **always** have missing edge cases. Get into the habit of identifying those edge cases as early as possible, and get clarification from the person who gave the requirements. Some edge cases here I can think of: what if the scrambled list matches more than one match ("ogd" = "dog" or "god"); should the comparison be case-sensitive ("god" vs "God"); what if the file has a blank line; what if the file has multiple words on one line.

Comment: @Alex for example, say you asked for clarification on the "god"/"dog" question. and the person said- "ok, if the scrambled word exactly matches an unscrambled word ("god" or "dog"), return the one that was present. Otherwise, return the first match alphabetically." This would require you to redo your whole algorithm. Now you *would* need `HashMap<String, List<String>>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should break this task down into smaller parts. Check each one works before moving on to the next.

First you need a method that turns a word into a key. A string containing the letters of the word alphabetised is a good key. So write something that passes the test:

```
assertEquals("dgo", createKey("dog");
assertEquals("act", createKey("cat");
```

Next you need to populate your map with words from your list. You need something that passes this test:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
addToMap(map,"dog");
assertEquals("dog", map.get("dgo");
```

Your `addToMap()` method will make use of `createKey()`.

It should now be clear that you can use the map you've created, and `createKey()` to find "dog" from any ordering:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
addToMap(map,"dog");
assertEquals("dog", map.get(createKey("odg"));
```

You can encapsulate this into a method, so that:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
addToMap(map,"dog");
assertEquals("dog", getFromScrambledWord(map,"odg"));
```

All that's left is to put it all together:

- Loop through your dictionary file and call `addToMap()` for each line
- Loop through your scrambled-word file, call `getFromScrambledWord()` for each one, print the result

If you also need to put this list in alphabetical order, then instead of printing it, store the result in a `List`, sort the list then loop through it to print.

---

I've deliberately made this not very object-oriented, because you're clearly a beginner. To make things more OO, make the Map a private field in a class of your own:

```
public class WordStore {
    private final Map<String,String> words = new HashMap<>();

    public void addWord(String word) {
       // your implementation here
    }

    public String getFromScrambled(String scrambledWord) {
       // your implementation here
    }
}
```

So the test would be more like:

```
WordStore store = new WordStore(); // the Map is inside the WordStore
store.addWord("dog"); // like addToMap()
assertEquals("dog", store.getFromScrambled("odg"));
```